# Components not appearing in window

Tags: java

I am writing a program that has multiple text area separated by tabs. It works fine, except that when I first compile it none of the components appear on the window; it is solid grey. When I resize the window, though, they appear and the program runs fine.

Any suggestions as to why this occurs and how to fix it?

Comment: Is this on Linux with Compiz enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Components need to be added to the frame before the frame is made visible.

If you add components after the frame is visible then you need to use:

```
panel.add( someComponent );
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a call to pack() on your top level component before calling setVisible(true)?